# Cannot get 2 divs side by side inside another div

Tags: html, css

I need your help,

How can I get the other (red) div to line-up nicely to the right beside the blue div inside of the main div. I have attached a pic of the problem below:

[image]

Here is the code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  background: rgb(132, 132, 132);
}
.centerObject {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -400px;
  /* Half of Width */
  margin-top: -300px;
  /* Half of Height */
  background: rgb(212, 208, 200);
  border: 2px ridge rgb(75, 75, 75);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="centerObject">
    <div id="a" style="width: 200px; height: 100%; border: 1px solid blue;"></div>
    <div id="b" style="width: 597px; height: 100%; border: 1px solid red; float: right;"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `float` both divs, and then in `div#a` you need to subtract the width of the border:

```
<div id="a" style="width: 198px; height: 100%; border: 1px solid blue; float:left;"></div>

<div id="b" style="width: 597px; height: 100%; border: 1px solid red; float: right;"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add this CSS:

```
.centerObject div {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    background: rgb(132, 132, 132);
}
.centerObject {
    width:800px;
    height:600px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-400px;
    /* Half of Width */
    margin-top:-300px;
    /* Half of Height */
    background: rgb(212, 208, 200);
    border: 2px ridge rgb(75, 75, 75);
}
.centerObject div {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="centerObject">
    <div id="a" style="width: 200px; height: 100%; border: 1px solid blue;"></div>
    <div id="b" style="width: 597px; height: 100%; border: 1px solid red; float: right;"></div>
</div>
```

One issue is that your child divs are wider than their parent (counting their borders), so `box-sizing:border-box;` will fix that. Then by using `display:inline-block;` you can get them to appear side by side (they're block elements by default).

Answer (score 2):

The quickset way to fix that is swapping the position of the two `<div>`

```
<div id="b">...</div>
<div id="a">...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding "float: left" to #a and "vertical-align: top" to #b. Also you may want to add a clearfix to the centerObject div. here you can read more about clearfix. [ClearFix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add float: left; to a element's style as well. And lower the width by 1px to account for the border.

```
<div id="a" style="width: 200px; height: 100%; border: 1px solid blue; float: left;"></div>
<div id="b" style="width: 596px; height: 100%; border: 1px solid red; float: left;"></div>
```

Comment: That alone won't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    html {
        background: rgb(132,132,132);
    }
    .centerObject {
        width:800px;
        height:600px;
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-400px; /* Half of Width */    
        margin-top:-300px; /* Half of Height */
        background: rgb(212,208,200);
        border: 2px ridge rgb(75,75,75);
    }

    .centerObject  div{
        float: left;
      }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="centerObject">

    <div id="a" style="width: 200px; height: 100%; border: 1px solid blue;"></div>

    <div id="b" style="width: 596px; height: 100%; border: 1px solid red;"></div>

</div>
```